# Does anyone here know how to user Randoop with Dependency Inject of Spring?

Tags: randoop

I am working on Randoop, and I don't seem to get the library generate JUnit for my spring application.
It can test for non-spring project only.
Any help will be appreicated.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can understand exactly what problem you are having?  From a vague English description, it is hard to provide advice.